# Sumar días a una fecha de la semana PHP

Tags: php, date

Estoy tratando que conforme se recorra el for hasta que llegue a final de mes. Quiero que aparezca el acrónimo del nombre del día. El problema es que en todos me aparece Mié, no avanza con el for la función. Sugerencias?

```
$a_date = date('Y-m-d');
$last = date("t", strtotime($a_date));
function dias($date)
{
  if($date == 'Sun') return 'Dom';
  if($date == 'Mon') return 'Lun';
  if($date == 'Tue') return 'Mar';
  if($date == 'Wed') return 'Mié';
  if($date == 'Thu') return 'Jue';
  if($date == 'Fri') return 'Vie';
  if($date == 'Sat') return 'Sáb';
}

for ($i=1; $i <= $last; $i++)
{
$output.= '<th class="tags no-sort">'.$i.' '.dias(date('D'), strtotime(date('w') . "+$i days")).'</th>';
}
```

Comment: ya revisaste el parámetro que le pasas a la función dias?

Comment: Ya lo edité se me desapareció el date :S, aún así no funciona

Comment: a dias le pasas dos parametros pero solo tiene uno

Comment: Ya funciona, gracias René, la coma no iba ahí.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob publica tu respuesta, como lo solucionaste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este fue el código que apliqué:

```
$a_date = date('Y-m');
$last = date("t", strtotime($a_date));
function dias($date)
{
  if($date == 'Sun') return 'Dom';
  if($date == 'Mon') return 'Lun';
  if($date == 'Tue') return 'Mar';
  if($date == 'Wed') return 'Mié';
  if($date == 'Thu') return 'Jue';
  if($date == 'Fri') return 'Vie';
  if($date == 'Sat') return 'Sáb';
}
  $x = 0;
  for ($i=1; $i <= $last; $i++)
  {
    $output.='<th class="tags no-sort">'.$i.' '.dias(date('D', strtotime($a_date. ' + '.$x.' days'))).'</th>';
    $x = $x + 1;
  }
```

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras mejorar tu codigo con una funcion PHP que emula los enums:
The SplEnum class
http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php

Esa es la forma correcta y eficiente de hacerlo.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para formatear fechas en diferentes idiomas se utiliza [strftime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) configurando bien los [locales](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php):

Eso sí, el sistema donde corre ese PHP debe tener bien configurados los "locale" que se quieran utilizar.